# How do I create a Google Script to move information from one sheet to another?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a Google Script to take answers that have been filled out in a form and put them into specific cells on a different spread sheet. For example, I want to be able to take the information from cell C1 on SheetA and paste it into cell B5 on SheetB. I also want to be able to specify a row to pull the information from, such as placing an X in column Y. So my thought is: **variable x = row number that contains an 'X' in column Y**. Followed up with: **copy C(x) from SheetA to B5 of SheetB**. I would like to be able to create this as a Google Script I can run straight from Google Apps. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to accomplish this having never used Javascript or Google Script prior.

Thank you for any help that can be provided.

Comment: If you're "trying to create" then please paste the code of your attempt and the first problem you have. Try solving each issue as you face them and when you get stuck you ask for that specific issue here. The way you asked now is actually just "Can someone code this for me?"

Answer (score 0):

I would start by working through the spreadsheet tutorial for reading/writing. It should walk you through creating the script and the code to access your spreadsheets. From there you might figure out what more specific questions you have:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets